# How to display alternate values from a table, column having values 'M' and 'F' (Oracle DB)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

It was asked to me in one of my interview.

I have a table with column values as M and F in it, I want to display below output using a SQL query.

```
Row 1 'M'
Row 2 'F'
Row 3 'M'
Row 4 'F'
Row 5 'M'
Row 6 'F'
.
.
.
etc..
```

Thanks,

Comment: But do you have an equal number of male and female records?  What happens if this isn't the case?

Comment: Please try showing us your query and ask doubt where you are having logical trouble instead of asking us do your work.

Comment: @ Tim :- Yes the number of M and F's are same.

Comment: @Vimal:- I don't have the query to show you but I guess below query will work as suggested below in the post                                                             

SELECT owner,decode(to_char(mod(ROWNUM,2)),'0','M','1','F') FROM all_objects WHERE ROWNUM < 100;

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, it will return M or F based for alternate rows

SELECT owner,decode(to_char(mod(ROWNUM,2)),'0','M','1','F') FROM all_objects WHERE ROWNUM < 100;

Comment: Thanks, this make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Assume table structure is below

```
create table test(
  gender char(1),
  name   varchar(50)
);
```

Your query should look like

```
select 'Row '||rownum||' '||chr(39)||gender||chr(39) result_data from test;
```

- `rownum` gives number 1,2,3 etc.
- `chr(39)` is single quote character `'`
- `||` is used for string concatination

result should be

```
Row 1 'M'
Row 2 'F'
Row 3 'M'
Row 4 'F'
Row 5 'M'
Row 6 'F'
```